# Logic to determine WMA( Monthly Close,30) CROSSED ABOVE WMA(Monthly Close,50)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, charts, stock

I'm trying to implement this -> [scanner](https://chartink.com/screener/boss-scanner-for-btst) in python. I have implemented 10 out of 11 filters. I'm unable to implement WMA( Monthly Close,30) CROSSED ABOVE WMA(Monthly Close,50) filter and I have no clue how to implement CROSSED ABOVE operation on two pandas series.

I have WMA function which will take close and returns the calculated WMA in pandas series.

```
def wma(col, period):
    indicator_wma = WMAIndicator(close=col, window=period)
    wma_df = indicator_wma.wma()
    return wma_df
```

I hope some one will shed some light on this. Thanks in advance.

https://chartink.com/screener/boss-scanner-for-btst

Answer (score 0):

```
wma_30 = wma(close_column, period)
wma_50 = wma(close_column, period)
```

If `30` is crossing `50` then
`(wma_30 > wma_50)` is changing from `0` to `1`
`cross_30_above_50 = (wma_30 >wma_50).astype(int).diff()`
`cross_30_above_50` will be `1` where `30 wma` is crossing `50 wma`

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. Unfortunately chartink uses different logic for calculating CROSSED ABOVE WMA functionality. I contacted the support team and they shared the logic. I'll post it here so it will be useful for others.
current month's WMA 30 greater than current month's WMA 50 (current month WMA 50)
and
previous month's WMA 30 to be less than previous month's WMA 50. (PREVIOUS month's WMA 50)